# Counter++ in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#-4.0

I understand using an iterator++ inside Parallel.ForEach is not a good option but right now i'm forced to use a counter inside a Parallel.ForEach loop, counter is used to pick up column names of a dynamic object at runtime.Any suggestion what would be the best option?.I read somewhere at StackOverflow that using "Interlocked" is again a bad design inside Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on why you need to have the counter? If you're just iterating over the columns of a dynamic object, unless you're expecting a massive amount of columns, I think parallelization might not be the best approach.

Comment: You are right Ryan but i was just trying out my luck if i can make use of Parallel.ForEach.The only block i feel is the counter otherwise the "Task" is clean and has no dependency on other objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need parallel processing, the indices will have to be pre-computed.  Something like `Enumerable.Range(0, cols.Length).ToArray()`.  Otherwise, each column will depend on the previous one, which obviously doesn't parallelize.

Comment: It can't be pre-computed.It's a row - column iteration.Through the iteration i need to parse each column for a check and based on that result i'll have to punch in the value for the column.So the counter depends on the intermediate cell check result.

Comment: The only value that can be pre-computed is the max column count and another check is to see if my counter exceeds the column count.I'm unable to post the code as i'm referring to many other interfaces.